# Prometheus metric relabel for specific value

Tags: regex, prometheus

I'm trying to use regex to create new label. My metric is:

```
some_metric{path="test/name/bar/foo"}
```

I want to get `bar` and put this in new label (`name`). I tried to relabel but it did not work (`prometheus.yml`):

```
    relabel_configs:
    - source_labels: [path]
      regex: "/test/name/(*.)/*."
      replacement: "$1"
      target_label: "name"
```

New output:

```
some_metric{path="test/name/bar/foo", name="bar"}
```

EDIT:

I removed `replacement` field and it update `regex` to `"test/name/(*.)/*."`. It resolved for me.

Comment: Try `regex: "test/name/([^/]+)/.*"`.

Comment: I removed `replacement` field and it worked.

Comment: So, you used `regex: "test/name/([^/]+)/.*"` and removed the `replacement` line?  If you keep `(*.)` in your regex, it should not match anything. `*.` must be `.*`

Comment: I think `regex: "test/name/([^/]*).*"` will work best here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
relabel_configs:
    - source_labels: [path]
      regex: "test/name/([^/]*).*"
      target_label: "name"
```

Note that the regex is defined with a string here, not a regex literal, so the first `/` is erroneous here.

Next, `*.` is a user error, `.*` matches any text. However, if you have more subparts, it will capture till the last `/`, and this can be avoided with a negated character class `[^/]+`.

*Details*:

- `test/name/` -  a literal fixed string
- `([^/]*)` - Capturing group 1: zero or more chars other than `/`
- `.*` - the rest of the line (zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible).

If